# Xamarin.Forms: How to request ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION?

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-permissions

Using XF 5.0.0 and Essentials 1.7.0. Targeting Android 11.0, API 30.
I'm already requesting ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION because I use Plugin.BLE.

I've added Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics to my XF app, and that seems to require the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission (the app crashes & an exception tells me so).

There's no item for ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in the Project Properties /  Required Permission list, so I manually added it to AndroidManifest.xml. It compiles, but still crashes.

I've also read that you can't request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION at the same time, that _FINE must be granted first, then you must request _BACKGROUND. Is that true?

Additionally, I'm requesting LocationAlways programatically:

```
var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationAlways>();
```

because it seems you can't do that one in the manifest.

And I'd be fine with requesting Background Location programatically, but `Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions` doesn't offer that.

So I'm stumped!

Does anyone know how to request both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION in a Xamarin.Forms app?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the [setup guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/get-started?tabs=windows%2Candroid#installation) for Android? Namely, the `override void OnRequestPermissionsResult` snippet? I use Xamarin.Essentials and AppCenter Analytics and I have no code referencing any ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission in my Android project.

Comment: @AndrewH: Yes, I did, and I follow the guide, and included OnRequestPermissionsResult() in my activity. 
Crash happens early: My App() constructor never even gets called :(
Are all of your permissions requested via the Android/Project>Properties>Manifest>permissions list, and/or are you using Permissions.RequestAsync() ?

Comment: Oh, and if I remove the Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics NuGet reference from my project, everything works perfectly.

Comment: [This checklist](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background) may provide some pointers. Seems like `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` is a deprecated permission. All my permissions are defined in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: Also where are you calling `AppCenter.Start()`?

Comment: Call to Appcenter.Start() is from OnStart() (which is probably wrong, colleague who wrote is new to Xamarin), but is currently commented out. So, not called & crash still occurs. Thanks for the help BTW :)

Comment: You need to call `AppCenter.Start()` to get the AppCenter functionality. It's preferred to be called in your MainActivity's `OnCreate()` override. I'm not sure if including the NuGets but not calling Start will cause any side effects.